# Diamond Operator and Fourier Coefficients

Tags: modular-forms

Let $d\in(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$, then one has the Diamond operator $\langle d \rangle$ acting on $M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ via $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\in\Gamma_0(N)$ in the usual Hecke way.

I was wondering, given some $f\in M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ with Fourier expansion $\sum a_nq^n$, if we know exactly how $\langle d\rangle $ acts on the Fourier coefficients $a_n$. I can't seem to find this result in the literature.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no straightforward formula for this, which is one of the reasons why one often works with the eigenspaces $M_k(\Gamma_1(N), \chi)$ instead.

Comment: Cheers for the help. So does that mean there is a formula when you know that $f\in M_k(\Gamma_1(N),\chi)$?

Comment: Yes, by definition we have $a_n(\langle d \rangle f) = \chi(d) a_n(f)$ for $f \in M_k(\Gamma_1(N), \chi)$ but this is a bit vacuous :-)

Comment: Oh, of course! That was a silly question. Cheers again!

Comment: How would I go about deriving a formula on the Fourier co-efficients for the general case? So for example when $\chi$ is not a Dirichlet character. Can I write such a relation by making a double coset  or left coset decomposition of a matrix element $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\in\Gamma_0(N)$ corresponding to $\langle d \rangle$?